# Убрать или исправить пустые кавычки

Tags: php, html

Как убрать или исправить эти пустые кавычки?

[image: Скриншот]

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

// вся    процедура работает на сессиях. Именно в ней хранятся данные пользователя,    пока он находится на сайте. Очень важно запустить их в самом начале    странички!!!
      session_start();
      include    ("basadata.php");// файл  должен быть в той же папке, что и все    остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь

 if (isset($_COOKIE['auto']) and    isset($_COOKIE['login']) and             isset($_COOKIE['password']))
        {//если есть    необходимые переменные
                 if ($_COOKIE['auto'] == 'yes') { // если    пользователь желает входить автоматически, то запускаем сессии
                                            $_SESSION['password']=strrev(md5($_COOKIE['password']))."b3p6f"; //в куках    пароль был не зашифрованный, а в сессиях обычно храним зашифрованный
                            $_SESSION['login']=$_COOKIE['login'];//сессия с логином 
                            $_SESSION['id']=$_COOKIE['id'];//идентификатор    пользователя
      setcookie("auto", "",    time()+9999999);//очищаем автоматический вход
                          }

                 }

 if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
 {

 //если существет логин и пароль в сессиях, то проверяем их и извлекаем аватар
 $login = $_SESSION['login'];
     $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,avatar FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND                       password='$password'",$db); 
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //извлекаем нужные данные о пользователе
  }
  ?>

  <? if ($myrow['login'] == $login) 
{ } 
else 
{ header('Location:http://v-sporte.net/feed.php'); }
 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/icon"> <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/icon">
 <title>Главная страница</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"></head>
     <body>
  <? include("blocks/header.php"); ?>
 <div class="main">
    <div class="leftColumn">
   <? include("blocks/form_auth.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="centerColumn">
 <h2 align='center'>Добро пожаловать!</h2>
 <h3>Мы любим спорт! Это часть нашей жизни. 
   Любите ли его Вы?.... Присоединяйтесь.</h3>
 <p>
 тут текст большой
   <br>
    <img align="middle" src="/images/welcome.jpg" width="400" height="270" />
  </p>
    </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="rightColumn"> </div>
<div class="hFooter"></div>
 </div>
 <? include("blocks/footer.php"); ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: <? include("blocks/header.php"); ?>
    <div class="main">

Попробуйте в одну строку писать.

Comment: это обычный text node, который в большинстве случаев никак себя не проявляет. Избежать их всех не получится никак, можно просто забить, т.к. см. п. 1.

Comment: alvoro, пробовал, не помогло.
Fike, он проявляется, еще как, у меня из-за него с версткой проблемы появляются.

Comment: Fike, проявляется, еще как, верстка не правильная в итоге у меня, много пустых мест.

Comment: Это пустое место или именно кавычки? Увидеть точно можно при просмотре HTML, а не там, откуда скриншот. Если пустота без кавычек и плывёт вёрстка - кривая вёрстка. Если кавычки всё-таки присутствуют, то искать где они лепятся в blocks/*.php.

Comment: @lifting, на чем основывается ваша уверенность, что дело в текстнодах? Кроме пары пикселей при отступах не помню за ними ничего интересного.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эти пустые кавычки появляются по причине того что ваш файл или файлы созданы в кодировке UTF-8 с BOM. это какие-то там пару символов которые доставляет текстовый редактор в начале файла для того чтобы идентифицировать кодировку. В общем вам нужно найти редактор который умеет сохранять файлы без BOM и пересохранить все свои PHP в нем. Кавычки пропадут. А да еще между  открывающим `?>` и закрывающим `<?` не должно быть пробелов в вашем случаи.

Answer (score 0):

Во всех файлах PHP, которые заканчиваются на `?>` удали эти символы `?>`